# T-SQL Clear duplicates records , update different field on first duplicate record and delete others

Tags: csv, duplicates, delete-row

ID        STOKKODU    Modeller

144    AL.57.00067   4313
157    AL.57.00067   4314
64          AL.57.00067 4307
9             AL.57.00067 4304
26       AL.57.00067   4305
216    AL.57.00067   4320
2955  AL.57.00067 3444
2927  AL.57.00067 3441
3202  AL.57.00067 3458

I Want to do this and delete duplicates.
ID      STOKKODU  Modeller 
144   AL.57.00067    4313,4314,4307,4304,4305,4320,3444,3441,3458

Comment: Any reason why you don't want a second table listing the models of each ID? Multi-valued fields breaks all sorts of rules and generally makes your life difficult when using them. Unless this is just going to be text to display as-is that is.

Comment: Will you for instance want to find all rows that contains model 4304?

Comment: Yes Lasse i'll do that as you describe after this step.

Comment: Why ID: 144 ? It's much easier to do this automatically if you SORT the "equal" records ASC or DESC and merge the Modeller Fields in the record that schould stay in the DB.

Comment: No i just want delete all duplicated record. Before to do this i want to save all different models on first row.

Comment: Stefan problem is not on sorting for simple just collobrating values before delete records. Dont care "144" or other. You can sort.